# PHP Array sort by criteria

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array but I want to sort it by my criteria.

I want if "country" and "top" are the same then they heve to be on one place.
Slightly below give an example of what I mean.

```
$array = array(
    array("city" => "New York", "country" => "USA", "top" => "1"),
    array("city" => "London", "country" => "UK", "top" => "1"),
    array("city" => "Sofia", "country" => "BG", "top" => "1"),
    array("city" => "Belgrad", "country" => "SRB", "top" => "2"),
    array("city" => "Varna", "country" => "BG", "top" => "2"),
    array("city" => "LA", "country" => "UK", "top" => "1"),
    array("city" => "Bat", "country" => "USA", "top" => "1")
);
```

Here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [city] => New York
            [country] => USA
            [top] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [city] => London
            [country] => UK
            [top] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [city] => Sofia
            [country] => BG
            [top] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [city] => Belgrad
            [country] => SRB
            [top] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [city] => Varna
            [country] => BG
            [top] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [city] => LA
            [country] => USA
            [top] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [city] => Bat
            [country] => UK
            [top] => 1
        )
)
```

I want this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array 
                (
                    [city] => New York
                    [country] => USA
                    [top] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [city] => LA
                    [country] => USA
                    [top] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [top_cities] => 2
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array 
                (
                    [city] => London
                    [country] => UK
                    [top] => 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [city] => Bat
                    [country] => UK
                    [top] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [top_cities] => 2
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array 
                (
                    [city] => Sofia
                    [country] => BG
                    [top] => 1
                )
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [city] => Belgrad
            [country] => SRB
            [top] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [city] => Varna
            [country] => BG
            [top] => 2
        )
)
```

Criteria(must match):
Country
Top
and count how top have in this array(sum)

I will be very grateful if someone give a idea how to handle with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be your expected output is wrong, or very unclear for a logic.

Comment: Start with `foreach`

Comment: @u_mulder okay but then. Did you have idea how to make it?

Comment: @bansi I post the result that i want.

Comment: Check country and place values into subarrays.

Comment: In your output, element 0 and 1 makes sense, even element 2, if only one sub item no need for `top_cities` but for element 3, and 4 cannot find a logic, can you explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. There is amall modification in the result. But I believe it will work for you

```
$array = array(
    array("city" => "New York", "country" => "USA", "top" => "1"),
    array("city" => "London", "country" => "UK", "top" => "1"),
    array("city" => "Sofia", "country" => "BG", "top" => "1"),
    array("city" => "Belgrad", "country" => "SRB", "top" => "2"),
    array("city" => "Varna", "country" => "BG", "top" => "2"),
    array("city" => "LA", "country" => "UK", "top" => "1"),
    array("city" => "Bat", "country" => "USA", "top" => "1")
);

$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $newArray[$val['country']][] = $val;
}
print_r($newArray);
```